# Setting status code for exception raised in load() function in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I have a `load()` route function that may throw a "maintenance mode" error if the backend is under maintenance. This may happen in `__layout`, `load()` or elsewhere in the frontend:

```
function load() {
    if(looksLikeDataIsUnderMaintennce) throw new UnderMaintenanceError();
}
```

Then I am catching this error in `__error.svelte` to display a more specific error message instead of "HTTP 500 We are on fire".

```
<script context="module">

    /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Load} */
    export function load({error, status}) {
        const maintenance = error.name === "UnderMaintenanceError";
        return {
            props: {
                title: `${status}`,
                message: error.message,
                maintenance: maintenance,
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let maintenance;
</script>

<div class="container">
    {#if maintenance}
        <h1 class="text-center">{chainName} data under maintenance, we are back in X minutes</h1>
    {:else}
        <h1 class="text-center">HTTP {title} error</h1>

        <pre>{message}</pre>
    {/if}
</div>
```

By default, SvelteKit serves exceptions with HTTP status code 500 (internal error). For maintenance, I would like to change the HTTP status code from 500 to more specific `HTTP 503 Service  Unavailable` as that's the preferred HTTP status code for maintenance and temporarily unavailability. I could not find a direct way to do this - returning `status` from `__error.load` does not seem to do the trick.

Is there a way to change the HTTP status code for thrown exceptions and error handler in SvelteKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object with a `status` property, like in [this example from the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints). That will automatically show the error page. You can pass more props if you want more information about the error.

So something like this:

```js
export async function get() {
    // If under maintenance
    return {
        status: 503 
    };
}
```

UPDATE:

For some reason, I can't get the error message to propagate in the `get` endpoint function, so if you want to pass the error around it seems you need to use the `load` function from that page, like so:

```html
<script lang='ts' context='module'>
    export function load({ error }) {
        console.log(error);
        
        return {
            status: 503,
            error: new UnderMaintenanceError(),
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something or if it's just a bug.

Comment: Probably good to open a discussion issue on SvelteKit. Although something like this is not common, it is not rare either, and this part of SvelteKit hasn't seen a lot of documentation/discussion yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Odilf's answer, we were able to this in the `load()` function in `__layout`:

```html
<script context="module">
  import { checkChainMaintenance } from "$lib/chain/maintenance";

  /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Load} */
  export function load({ params }) {
    // Check for the data maintenance status.
    // If under maintenance, trigger __error with a special
    // layout and message.
    try {
      checkChainMaintenance(params.chain);
    } catch(error) {
      return { status: 503, error };
    }
    return {};
  }
</script>

<slot />
```

[See full example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/src/routes/trading-view/%5Bchain%5D/__layout.svelte).